# Having an independent event with animals

Tags: probability, statistics

In a building for 24 apartments. It is known that there is only one dog in 8 apartments and a single cat in 6 apartments. How many apartments must have cat and dog for events "have dog" and " have cat" to be independent?

I know that

Events $C$ and $D$ are independent if
$$P(C\cap D)=P(C)P(D)\ .$$

probability of cats 8/24 = 1/3
and probability of dogs 6/24 = 1/4
probability of cats or dog =(1/4+1/3) = 7/12? I have to find a number that do the probability be 1/1. Am I riht??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, the statistical definition of independence is

$P(C\cap D)=P(C)P(D)$

Now P(C)P(D) = $\dfrac13 \cdot \dfrac14 = \dfrac{1}{12}$,

and $P(C\cap D)$ is the probability that an apartment has both cats and dogs.

Thus number of such apartments = $\dfrac{1}{12}\cdot24 = 2$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(C)P(D)=\frac{1}{12}=\frac{2}{24}.$$
Therefore, two apartments must have both a cat and a dog for $C$ and $D$ to be independent.

Comment: I did not get it.

Comment: For the equality $P(C\cap D)=P(C)P(D)$ to hold it must be true that two out of 24 apartments have both types of pets.

Comment: I am sorry, buy but why?